# How to get source maps to provide correct stack traces?

Tags: javascript, source-maps, babeljs

I'm trying to get source maps for babel working correctly.

I want two things in my stack traces.

1. The full path of the files
2. The correct line numbers (src code not compiled)

Results from testing:

- When `"sourceMaps": "inline"` I get 1, but not 2.
- When `"sourceMaps": true` I get 2, but not 1.

Answer (score 0):

The following works.

```
    "sourceMaps": "inline",
    "retainLines": true
```